# What exactly the first argument `identifier` in Objective-C?

Tags: arguments

Please note that this could be a very basic question. Learning Objective-C from a background of JavaScript. I think I need an extra explanation about what exactly `identifier` argument in the following?

```
- (BOOL)isEqualTo:(NSString *)identifier;
```

Comment: Its the first argument.

Comment: Please do research into what you are going to ask beforehand, make an attempt at trying to solve your own problem. This shows absolutely no attempt at finding out what it is.

Comment: There are countless tutorials on Objective-C. Please take the time to go through several of them. A question this basic really has no place on stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`identifier` parameter is a string you need to compare to. For example:

```
NSString* yourString = @"Hello"; 
BOOL match = [yourString isEqualToString: @"aString"]; //currently returns NO

//handle match value according to your needs, e.g with if-else syntax.  
if (match) { 
    //YES flow
}
else {
    //NO flow
}
```

where `@"aString"` is a method parameter, named as `identifier` (in your case) to be used in `isEqualToString` API's implementation of `Foundation` framework.

Comment: Since the OP clearly has no basic understanding of Objective-C, it would be helpful to show how the return value should be used as well.

Comment: @rmaddy ok, good point.

Answer (score 1):

`identifier` is the name of the object that is passed as an argument by the sender (or caller, namely you in your code).`[anObject isEqualTo: @"Something"];`

In this particular case you'll never actually use it, it's the name the object you send gets referred by inside of the implementation of `isEqualTo`. You can't see the Apple code but you know that they use `identifier` to name your object in the context of that method. This pointer must point to an instance of the NSString class.